# HTML and CSS How can I align all the dates so that they are all even in height in a table?

Tags: html, css

The dates with events under them are not aligned correctly how can I fix them so that everything fits evenly?

```css
.main-calender,
table {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}

.header-month {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

tr,
th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
/*  =============
    typography 
    =============  */

.main-calender tbody {
  background-image: url(/images/background.jpg);
  background-color: #475465;
}

.header-month {
  color: black;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

th {
  background: #475465;
  color: #fff;
}

td {
  color: #fff;
}

.main-calender span {
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

/*  =============
    components
    =============  */

td:hover {
  background: #219ebc;
}

/* link (school) */
.link-main span {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* link (school) */
.main-calender a {
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none underline;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-calender">
  <div class="header-month">
    <h3>October 2022</h3>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>The</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6"></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          2 <br />

          <a href="https://losrios.edu/" target="_blank">School</a>
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
          11 <br />
          <span>Holiday</span>
        </td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>
          17 <br />
          <span>Trip </span>
        </td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm sort of new to using tables so I'm not sure what mistake I made. I want the dates "2" "11" and "17" to be the same line height as the other dates and for the events under the dates which are"school" "holiday" and "trip" I want them to be at kind of the baseline end of the box so they can be out of the way. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First add new classes to reference the elements to change their styles easier (the new classes `box`, `box__number` and `box__adt`) and refactor some `html` markup. Also set `position: relative` to the `box` div elements and `position: absolute` so that the height of the `box__adt` div elements does not affect the height of their parents. (Notice: the `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` properties are for centering it horizontally).

Try:

```css
.main-calender,
table {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}

.header-month {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

tr,
th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

/*  =============
typography 
=============  */

.main-calender tbody {
  background-image: url(/images/background.jpg);
  background-color: #475465;
}

.header-month {
  color: black;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

th {
  background: #475465;
  color: #fff;
}

td {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.main-calender span {
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

/*  =============
components
=============  */

td:hover {
  background: #219ebc;
}

/* link (school) */
.link-main span {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* link (school) */
.main-calender a {
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none underline;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
}

.box__adt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-calender">
  <div class="header-month">
    <h3>October 2022</h3>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>The</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6"></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="box">
          <div class="box__number">2</div>
          <div class="box__adt"><a href="https://losrios.edu/" target="_blank">School</a></div>
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td class="box">
          <div class="box__number">11</div>
          <div class="box__adt"><span>Holiday</span></div>
        </td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td class="box">
          <div class="box__number">17</div>
          <div class="box__adt"><span>Trip</span></div>
        </td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```